# How can i get store_id in Magento2 REST API

Tags: magento2, rest-api

How can i get store_id in Magento2 REST API and by passing store_id i want to show different store views in application using REST API.

Comment: Try the answer and let me know if you have any query.

Comment: yes i got, but i want separate stores views is there any api for that

Comment: Yes it is, but what exactly you want to achieve, can you please elaborate ?

Comment: i have select city option in website if i select particular city or place i want that id as store id and whole app must change based on that id

Comment: You need to make custom call for that, Call storeManager Interface in your custom API.

Comment: can u elaborate please. which parameters should i pass in api

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> storeStoreRepositoryV1

---

**Group repository interface**

```
http://magento.host/index.php/rest/V1/store/storeGroups
```

- `method : GET`
- `Authorization : Bearer <admin token>`

This will return `website_id`, `root_category_id`, `default_store_id`, `name`, `code`

---

**Store repository interface**

> This will return store id, website id and also code, in-short all data of store repository.

```
http://magento.host/index.php/rest/V1/store/storeViews
```

- `method : GET`
- `Authorization : Bearer <admin token>`

As per discussion,

**storeStoreConfigManagerV1**

---

```
http://magento.host/index.php/rest/V1/store/storeConfigs
```

- `method : GET`
- `Authorization : Bearer <token>`

Comment: after getting store code we should pass store code in
http://base.url/rest/{store code}/V1/categories

then we will get separate store Views

Comment: I was looking for website ids list and now I have it. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, happy coding 

Comment: Very useful answer!